# Django - Static images render

Tags: django, static, django-templates

I have a template that should render picture of each product.
But as result - URL for it has extra "static" in path

like that - 127.0.0.1:8000/**static**/static/photos/product1.png.

It should be just 127.0.0.1:8000/static/photos/product1.png

Is there any way to do it properly?

**model.py** saves it to "static/photos"

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos', default='http://placehold.it/700x400')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from .models import Category, Product

def product_list(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = {"object_list": queryset}
    return render(request, "product_list.html", context)
```

**template.html** is following

```
{% load static %}

{% for instance in object_list %}
    <p><img src="{% static instance.photo %}" /></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Uploaded files have nothing to do with static files, you need to work with `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` as static files are intended for things like stylesheets or JavaScript.

Comment: but what if I need to use uploaded pictures in my template? is there any way to render it without storing it in static?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/file-uploads/. It covers the whole topic.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
    <p><img src="{% static instance.photo %}" /></p>
{% endfor %}
```

To

```
 {% for instance in object_list %}
    <p><img src="{% static instance.photo.url %}" /></p>
 {% endfor %}
```